# Axis2 WebService Client: The given SOAPAction does not match an operation

Tags: soap, apache-axis, webservice-client

I have a test webservice developed with CXF running in my computer and I have been trying to make the client side with the "wsdl2java" function of Apache Axis2. I have already generated the code but I have the following error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The given SOAPAction http://service.taller1.webservices.spring.com/HolaMundoService/saludaHola does not match an operation.
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.spring.webservices.taller1.service.impl.HolaMundoServiceImplServiceStub.saludaHola(HolaMundoServiceImplServiceStub.java:182)
at mian.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Here the wsdl:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://impl.service.taller1.webservices.spring.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:ns1="http://service.taller1.webservices.spring.com/" name="HolaMundoServiceImplService" targetNamespace="http://impl.service.taller1.webservices.spring.com/">
  <wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/webservice-cfx-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HolaMundoService?wsdl=HolaMundoService.wsdl" namespace="http://service.taller1.webservices.spring.com/">
    </wsdl:import>
  <wsdl:binding name="HolaMundoServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:HolaMundoService">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="saludaHola">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="saludaHola">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="saludaHolaResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="HolaMundoServiceImplService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:HolaMundoServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name="HolaMundoServiceImplPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/webservice-cfx-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HolaMundoService"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're probably using the wrong action or the wrong schema binding.

The following may work for you:

```
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    OperationClient operationClient = client.createClient(ServiceClient.ANON_OUT_IN_OP);

    // creating message context
    MessageContext outMsgCtx = new MessageContext();
    // assigning message context’s option object into instance variable
    Options opts = outMsgCtx.getOptions();
    // setting properties into option
    opts.setTo(new EndpointReference("http://localhost:8080/webservice-cfx-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HolaMundoService"));
    opts.setAction(""); //your soap action is null
    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    auth.setUsername("user");
    auth.setPassword("pass");
    opts.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
    //Create the Soap Factory
    SOAPFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getSOAP11Factory();
    //Create the request envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = fac.getDefaultEnvelope();
    OMNamespace globalNs = fac.createOMNamespace("http://service.taller1.webservices.spring.com/", "ns1");
    // creating the payload
    OMElement method = fac.createOMElement("saludaHola", globalNs);
    method.setText("Hello");
    envelope.getBody().addChild(method);
    outMsgCtx.setEnvelope(envelope);
    operationClient.addMessageContext(outMsgCtx);
    operationClient.execute(true);
    MessageContext inMsgtCtx = operationClient.getMessageContext("In");
    //get the response
    SOAPEnvelope response = inMsgtCtx.getEnvelope();
    System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Good code to demonstrate how message construction works. You missed the envelope addition to the context (I added it)