# AxisFault: The given SOAPAction urn:anonOutInOp does not match an operation

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, apache-axis

I did a lot of search concerned with my question, like [Axis2 WebService Client: The given SOAPAction does not match an operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769806/axis2-webservice-client-the-given-soapaction-does-not-match-an-operation), And [Apache CXF - The given SOAPAction does not match an operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902874/apache-cxf-the-given-soapaction-does-not-match-an-operation).

I am quite new to the webservice technology, ok, here's the datail: `Launch Webservice Interface with CXF Framework, And We wrote client code with Axis2 Framework`, like below:

```
try {
       RPCServiceClient client = new RPCServiceClient();
       Options options = client.getOptions();   
       String address = "http://ip:port/yaoxie/service/orderInfoBean?wsdl"; 
       EndpointReference epf = new EndpointReference(address);  
       options.setTo(epf); 
       QName qname = new QName("http://spring.orderInfo/", "debitOrder");
       String par = "<orgs>test</orgs>";
       System.out.println("start to call");
       Object[] result = client.invokeBlocking(qname, new Object[] { par }, new Class[] { String.class });
       System.out.println("finished");
       System.out.println(result[0]);
    } catch (AxisFault e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And here's the WSDL description info:[WSDL info](https://github.com/jerrycave/druid/blob/master/wsdl.xml)

Then I got this error:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The given SOAPAction urn:anonOutInOp does not match an operation.
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:435)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:371)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:417)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.triffic.Axis2Demo.Axis2DemoTest.testClient(Axis2DemoTest.java:49)
at com.triffic.Axis2Demo.Axis2DemoTest.main(Axis2DemoTest.java:82)
```

What should I do, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    options.setAction("OperationName")
```

You should be able to get `operationName` by looking into the wsdl file